# Include/Exclude files (about their age) in powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to include (and therefore remove) all files older than 30 days. Additionally I want the oldest file to be preserved.

```
$Exclusion = (Get-ChildItem "$PATH" -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like "*.conf"} | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 1).name
Get-ChildItem "\\$PATH" -Recurse | Where {$_.creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | Remove-Item -Force -Include *.conf -Exclude $Exclusion
```

This doesn't work. My oldest file gets deleted too. Where is my error, or can't I combine include and exclude if both are .conf files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you dont sort the objects by age descdending and `-skip 1` (the oldest file).

I think a code like this should work.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\$PATH" -Recurse | Where {$_.creationtime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |Sort-Object creationtime -desc | select-object -skip 1 |  Remove-Item -Force -Include *.conf -Exclude $Exclusion
```

I don't have a powershell here to test.

Comment: I missed the forest for all the trees. Simple. Efficient! Thank you!

Comment: select-object -first 30 and it is perfect ;)